# How to pass temporary data from trigger to stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a windows forms application and `Customers` table on it and the according table in DB(`Customer`). When editing the `WinForm` table and clicking the save button there is `stored procedure` executing and updating the `Customer` table in DB. When the table updated, there is a `trigger` executing. `Trigger` executes some `stored procedure` for logging purposes and save the data to the log table. I need to pass `Environment.UserName` to the log table without saving it in `Customer` table i.e. I must pass it to the final log table, but i can't add it in `Customer` table as column. And I don't know how to do it. Is there any way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the username on the connection context (encode it as varbinary).

```
    DECLARE @a VARBINARY(128)
    SET @a = CAST('myuser' AS VARBINARY(128))
    SET CONTEXT_INFO @a
```

Where @a contains the encoded username. In your trigger you can then get the context info with the function `CONTEXT_INFO()` and decode it to a varchar.

```
    SELECT cast(CONTEXT_INFO() as VARCHAR(128))
```

Comment: In case when I call CONTEXT_INFO() from Management Studio, it will return NULL ?

Comment: the connection context is only available in the original connection. so if you did not do the `SET CONTEXT_INFO` it will indeed return null.

Comment: Thank you! I think this method the only possible way in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if passing parameters to triggers is good idea.

Please consider use `suser_sname()` function in trigger body to recognize user.

Another option is moving logic from trigger to stored procedure and passing information about cuurent user to stored procedure.

Comment: Agreed, but in my case suser_sname() returns the user name 'sa' not the windows user name.

Comment: Using 'sa' account to connect to database violates few security rules, but I perfectly understand that sometimes cost of big refactor is to high for project sponsors. Maybe some option for you is `host_name()` function which gives you information about user workstation name.